# fabricjs text to polygon

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have created a Text object, but now I have to create a polygon based on the points of this text.

This is how I created the text:

```
c = new fabric.Canvas("c");
ctx = c.getContext('2d');

Text = new fabric.Text("some text", {
    stroke:"rgb(0, 51, 78)",
    strokeWidth:9,
    fontSize:250
});

c.add(Text);
```

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible. Yes it is! is it easy, no it is not at all easy and the results will vary depending on the font. You can access the encoded font data for some fonts and create the polygons based on that data. That is how many 3D apps create their mesh fonts. If that data is not available or to difficult to get at you can apply bitmap to vector conversion which for fonts can work well, but is a complex and involved process that many times will involve some human tweaking to get just right.

Comment: Please (and I insist with the please), if you have an example or some useful link, please provide me something, I'm in a hurry.

Comment: I would ask myself, why do I need polygons??? as text is already vector based and can be drawn at any size to a wide range of devices/formats. Anyways the hint was not seen, sorry. First up on google search "webGL font to vector" was https://github.com/mattdesl/fontpath that will do the job, just hack and grab the triangulated font to create a fabric path object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your knowledge is far beyond mine. I will try to find an easy way, since fontpath is too much for me.